# On Radio Button show text area and store its value in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following on the previous help, I am stuck at this problem and hopefully it is the last.

I have this row of radio buttons and clicking each gets the id(row id) of it's parent div and its value and puts it in a text area eg 14001290~01~01:CD2, 15489587~03~01:CM (anything before : is the row id and after is the value of the radio )

There is also on hover show/hide, and count number of radio button checked.

The above part is done(slight changes needed instead of comma | needs to be the delimiter). Now what needs to be done is -- when the Missing Radio button is checked, then a text area shows and the text inputted in it needs to be added to the row id and radio button value.

**Current Output**

47596528~02~03:CM,78965822~01~02:CD1  
Required output now eg:

**Required** 
14001290~01~01:CD2:Address is missing|15489587~03~01:CM:Payment is missing|78965822~01~02:CD1:The certificate is missing.

(comma needs to be replaced by |)

**[FULL CODE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/19eggs/jj4Uv/18/)**

```
$("input:radio").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.r-title, .m-notes').hide();
    var totalRd = $('table').find(':not(.pend) > input:radio:checked').length;
    var clicked =[];
    $("#totalRd .rd-count").html(totalRd);
    $(this).siblings('.r-title, .m-notes').show(); 
    $('table').find(":not(.pend) >input[type=radio]:checked").each(function() {
        var selectedId = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id'); //gets the row id
        clicked.push(selectedId+":"+this.value); //adds the row id and value of radio
        $(".m-notes").keyup(function(){
            var mNotes = $(this).val();
            $('#output').text(mNotes);
        });
    }); //checked
    $("#inputhere").val(clicked);
});
```

Any new approach are very welcome.

*****Update*************

Tried quite a few ways but no luck. Can gurus help me here or show me the direction? I don't mind a complete re-write of the code.

Comment: Hi! Just wondered if this is at all possible...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need ? Here, I have disabled the input, on radio button click or change, but you can do the modification as per your requirement.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="radio" id="r1" value="1" name="someRadioGroup" checked="true"/>R1
<input type="text" id="r1edit" value="Enter your name"/><br/> 
<input type="radio" id="r2" value="2" name="someRadioGroup"/> R2<br/>
<input type="radio" id="r3" value="3" name="someRadioGroup"/> R3<br/>
<textarea id="log" style="width: 400px;" value=""></textarea>
```

**js:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name=someRadioGroup]:radio").change(function () {
        if ($("#r1").attr("checked")) {
            $('#r1edit:input').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        else {
            $('#r1edit:input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
        $('#log').val($('#log').val()+ $(this).val() + '|');
    })
});
```

Comment: Hi! Shree, Thanks for your reply. It is similar but not quite.

Input textarea only shows when the missing radio button is clicked and  the value of the textarea should be displayed along with the row id and value of the radi button...Any ideas how to go about it.